# The closure of the orbit of each point of a torus in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $\mathbb T^n:= \mathbb R^n / \mathbb Z^n$ be the torus in $\mathbb R^n$.

We use the notation $[x]:=x+\mathbb Z^n$.

Any vector $v\in \mathbb R^n$ determines a smooth flow $\phi_t$ on $\mathbb T^n$ by

$$\phi_t([x]):=[x+tv].$$

Here is my question: for each $x\in \mathbb R^n$, I want to find a vector subspace $S$ of $\mathbb R^n$ such that the following three things are satisfied:

(1) $v\in S$

(2) $[x+S]\subset \mathbb T^n$ is compact

(3) $\phi_t$-orbit of $[x]$ is dense in $[x+S]$.

In the case when $n=2$ this is relatively easy. Since we can take $S$ to be either a single line or $\mathbb R^2$ depending on whether the slope of $v$ is rational. For general $n$, I am not sure about how to construct the $S$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The result you want to look for is the "Kronecker–Weyl Theorem". The closure of $\{[x+tv]\colon t\in\Bbb R\}$ will be a subtorus of $\Bbb T^n$; more precisely, it is the subtorus defined by all rational linear relations among the components of the vector $v$. In particular, if the components of $v$ are linearly independent over $\Bbb Q$, then the closure is all of $\Bbb T^n$. (This can be translated back to $\Bbb R^n$ if needed, but the result is cleanest when working directly inside $\Bbb T^n$.)

Comment: If the components of $v$ has maximally $r$ linearly independent vectors over rationals, is the subtorus and $S$ both of dimension $r$ too?

Comment: That's correct. For example, if $v$ is a multiple of a vector with rational components, then the subtorus has dimension $1$ (it coincides with the $\phi_t$-orbit).

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to describe $S$ (not the subtorus) more explicitly?

Comment: It's the subspace of all points whose components satisfy the same $\Bbb Q$-linear relations as the components of $v$.